# Tools for inline replacing JSON file

Tags: javascript, json

Are there any command tools that allow modify json file?

e.g.

**data.json**

```
{
"foo": {"bar": 123}
}
```

And I need a command line tool that replace the value, e.g. from 123 to 234

```
./update-json -k "foo.bar" -v 234
```

Pls note the above json string can be in any valid format, e.g. minified or not, so a json parser should be needed. (instead of sed/awk)

Answer (score 1):

you might use [sed](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sed)

```
$> sed s/123/234/ data.json > newdata.json
```

output: newdata.json

```
{
    "foo": {"bar": 234}
}
```

Use global flag `g` if you need to replace every occurence of `123` in this way: `s/123/234/g`

Otherwise you may also use jsawk: [github.com/micha/jsawk](http://github.com/micha/jsawk)

Comment: I have updated my question, I want by specifying the json key, I can have a robust way to replace its value, e.g. foo.bar => 234

Comment: Yes, seems this is the solution, can you please update your answer? Thanks